# When can we expect Plasma 5.3 to be available for Kubuntu users

Tags: kubuntu, kde, backport, plasma-5, kde5

Plasma 5.3 has been released in Kubuntu backport ppa, but not in the main ppa. What is generally the timelines that a backport is available in the main ppa.

What are the reasons why I should not go for backport ppa. From documentation is seems very scary to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Kubuntu PPA**

A list of available Kubuntu ppa's: https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa

The Kubuntu Backports PPA: https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports is

> Backports of new versions of KDE Platform, Plasma and Applcations as
>   well as major KDE apps for Kubuntu.

**Main PPA**

What is a 'main ppa' ?
Do you mean the Ubuntu repositories main ?: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Or do you mean the Ubuntu backports: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

By a Kubuntu developer: http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2015/05/21/%23kubuntu-devel.html#t13:39

> BluesKaj  is plasma 5.3 in the regular kubuntu-backports yet or is the
>   ppa still needed ?    13:39
>
> ...
>
> yofel BluesKaj: PPA, it won't get into
>   backports 14:14